# Pycharm is not finding the functions in well known and working packages

Tags: pycharm, astronomy, pyephem

I am using Pycharm to develop a script, and I would like to compute the beta angle for a specific satellite, i.e the angle between a satellite's orbital plane around Earth and the geocentric position of the sun.

To achieve this, I need to obtain the Sun's RA and DEC, and I explored the packages pyephem and PyAstronomy, with their methods ephem.SUN() and pyals.sunpos() respectively.

The problem is that it seems like these method are not defined, and pycharm raises the error `Cannot find reference 'sunpos' in '__init__.py'`.

I tried to explore the libraries content, and indeed it seems like those functions are not defined, but there must be a problem, since it is possible to find multiple tutorials online that use those functions.

Comment: Did you import the libs in your init.py file? You need to not only install them but also import into your code.

Comment: I don't have an __init__.py file for my project, and why would I need it now? I have never added the libs in init files but everything has always worked fine.
Why should I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The `Sun` class (note that only the first letter is capitalized, not all three) is loaded dynamically in PyEphem from the C-language module it compiles behind the scenes. This loop creates `Sun` plus an object for each planet:

https://github.com/brandon-rhodes/pyephem/blob/664f9e74cc7a39e839736e373b88b161a6877959/ephem/__init__.py#L92

```
# We also create a Python class ("Mercury", "Venus", etcetera) for
# each planet and moon for which _libastro offers specific algorithms.

for index, classname, name in _libastro.builtin_planets():
    exec('''
class %(name)s(_libastro.%(classname)s):
    "Create a Body instance representing %(name)s"
    __planet__ = %(index)r
''' % dict(name=name, classname=classname, index=index))
```

Maybe in some future version I should abandon the loop and just have a stack of nine definitions that create the objects directly. It would duplicate the list of planets between both the C and Python code, which is what I was probably trying to avoid; but how often does that list change, anyway? And it would be more explicit, which is considered an advantage in Python code; and, IDEs would understand what is going on.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, Brandon, you are always very precise when answering questions.
What do you think should I do, then, in order to use the class?

Comment: I would suggest using examples in the PyEphem documentation. PyCharm should let you paste in or type in that code, even if PyCharm itself doesn't recognize those classes. Python will run the code, even if PyCharm doesn't understand it; Python runs code without asking PyCharm first, happily!

Comment: Indeed, it works. Thank you for the clarifications and the good work!

Comment: What about just having something like `star` that takes a string argument? It would make code that picks a planet from user input a lot more compact.

Comment: @orome — Could PyCharm validate that the string argument was the name of a planet? I had assumed that moving the planet identity from code to data would, besides making code more verbose, prevent validation of whether a string like 'Sun' was valid.